# iOS partial screen dialog for drop down listbox (android spinner) style control

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In iOS for the iPhone I want to make a control with similar appearance and behavior to the android spinner control when configured to behave like a drop down list box. Specifically when pressed a modal list of text options with radio buttons comes up and when one of them is pressed the list disappears and the control updates to that choice. Example:
[image: Android spinner example]

So far I have seen a full-screen option using [self presentViewController...] with a custom ViewController but I want a partial screen (like pictured above) solution. Does anyone know how to do this or could point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you didnt want to use the UIActionSheet and you wanted to make it reusable rather than adding a whole bund of UIViews to your current XIB, you could create a custom UIView with whatever interface you would need to populate it and use the interface builder to help make it look ok.

that view could have a message handler that posts the response that you would need to listen for.

then just init and load the view into your subviews and populate it

then post a message from the custom view to the handler you registered

so for your custom view you would have something like this.

```
@implementation SomeCustomView
+(SomeCustomView*)viewFromNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName{
    NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:NULL];
    NSEnumerator *nibEnumerator = [nibContents objectEnumerator];
    SomeCustomView *customView = nil;
    NSObject* nibItem = nil;
    while ((nibItem = [nibEnumerator nextObject]) != nil) {
        if ([nibItem isKindOfClass:[AADropDown class]]) {
            customView = (SomeCustomView*)nibItem;
            break;
        }
    }
    return customView;
}
-(void)someInitializationWith:(NSArray*)repeatableData andNotificationId:(NSString*)noteId{
//set your stuff up for the view here and save the notification id
}
...
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:Your_Notification_Id object:somevalue];
}
@end
```

and include other things, like in this case the tableview stuff or any other logic.

then in your viewcontroller you could call it like

```
__block id observer = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"customViewAction" object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    //deal with notification here
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: observer];
}];
SomeCustomView *cv =(SomeCustomView*) [SomeCustomView viewFromNibNamed:@"SomeCustomView"];
[cv someInitializationWith:arrayOptions andNotificationId:@"customViewAction"];
[self.view addSubview:cv];
```

and in your interface builder you will just need to make sure that the class of the view is set to your class type.

then you can easily reuse this code again whenever a user needs to  select something else in the same manner.

Comment: Did something similar using a custom UIViewController file that gets initialized with a button and an array of strings. It then decorates the button to look like a drop down listbox(combo box) and handles the text display. When pressed code calls a popup method that handles the rest. The code is included as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The native solution to this will be a UIActionSheet which on iPhone will appear from the bottom and be partial screen or on iPad be very similar to the android version.

You can find the documentation here: [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation on the solution suggested by AtomRiot.

On your view (xib or storyboard) make a button and assign this graphic to it. Don't worry if it appears stretched out in the editor. The code will make it a realizable graphic.
[image]
2X version[image]

Then include the following files in your project (copied below):
DDLBHelper.h
DDLBHelper.m

Then in your ViewController's .h file make links to the button:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *ddlbB;
- (IBAction)ddlbBClick:(id)sender;
```

In you ViewController's .m file make the following calls:

```
@synthesize ddlbB, choiceLabel;
DDLBHelper *mDDLBH;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *strings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Item 1", @"Item 2", @"Item 3", nil];
    mDDLBH = [[DDLBHelper alloc] initWithWithViewController:self button:ddlbB stringArray:strings currentValue:1];
}

- (IBAction)ddlbBClick:(id)sender {
    [mDDLBH popupList];
}
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    [mDDLBH adjustToRotation];
}
```

Works just like android.

Here are the files:
DDLBHelper.h

```
//  DDLBHelper.h
//  Created by MindSpiker on 9/27/12.

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@protocol DDLBHelperDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) itemSelected: (int)value;
@end

@interface DDLBHelper : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    id <DDLBHelperDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (retain) id delegate;

// external interface
- (id) init;
- (id) initWithWithViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController button:(UIButton *)button stringArray:(NSArray *)values currentValue:(int) currentValue;
- (void) popupList;
- (BOOL) isShown;
- (void) adjustToRotation;
- (int) getValue;
- (NSString *)getValueText;

@end
```

DDLBHelper.m

```
//  DDLBHelper.m
//  Created by MindSpiker on 9/27/12.

#import "DDLBHelper.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface DDLBHelper () {
@private
    UIViewController *mVC;
    UIButton *mButton;
    NSArray *mValues;
    int mValue;

    UITableView *mTV;

    UIView *mBackgroundV;

}

@end

@implementation DDLBHelper

@synthesize delegate;

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    mVC = nil;
    mButton = nil;
    mValues = nil;
    mValue = -1;
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithWithViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController button:(UIButton *)button stringArray:(NSArray *)values currentValue:(int) currentValue {
    self = [super init];

    // save pointers
    mVC = viewController;
    mButton = button;
    mValues = values;
    mValue = currentValue;

    [self setupButton];

    return self;
}

- (void) popupList{
    if (mBackgroundV == nil){
        mBackgroundV = [self setupBackgroundView];
        [mVC.view addSubview:mBackgroundV];
    }
    if (mTV == nil){
        mTV = [self setupTableView];
        [mVC.view addSubview:mTV];
    }
    [mTV reloadData];
    [mBackgroundV setHidden:NO];
    [mTV setHidden:NO];
}

- (BOOL) isShown{
    return !mTV.isHidden;
}

- (void) adjustToRotation{
    BOOL isShown = [self isShown];

    // remove the controls
    if (mBackgroundV != nil){
        [mBackgroundV removeFromSuperview];
        mBackgroundV = nil;
    }
    if (mTV != nil){
        [mTV removeFromSuperview];
        mTV = nil;
    }

    if (isShown){
        [self popupList];
    }
}

- (int) getValue{
    return mValue;
}

- (NSString *) getValueText{
    if (mValues != nil && mValue > -1) {
        if (mValues.count > mValue){
            return [mValues objectAtIndex:mValue];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void) updateButtonTitle{
    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@", [self getValueText]];

    [mButton setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void) setupButton {
    UIImage *buttonBG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sis_proceeds_ddlb.png"];
    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 45);
    UIImage *sizableImg = [buttonBG resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets];
    [mButton setBackgroundImage:sizableImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
    [self updateButtonTitle];
}

- (UIView *) setupBackgroundView{
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:mVC.view.bounds];
    [[v layer] setOpaque:NO];
    [[v layer] setOpacity:0.7f];
    [[v layer] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    return v;
}

- (UITableView *) setupTableView {
    CGRect rect = [self makeTableViewRect];
    UITableView *tv = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:rect style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [tv setDelegate:self];
    [tv setDataSource:self];
    [tv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[tv layer] setBorderWidth:2];
    [[tv layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
    [[tv layer] setCornerRadius:10];
    [mVC.view addSubview:tv];
    return tv;
}

- (CGRect) makeTableViewRect {
    float l=0.0, t=0.0, w=0.0, h=0.0, maxH=0.0, cellH=0.0, cellsH=0.0;

    // get 
    l = mButton.frame.origin.x;
    w = mButton.frame.size.width;
    t = mVC.view.bounds.origin.y + 50;
    maxH = mVC.view.bounds.size.height - 100;

    // get cell height
    UITableViewCell *c = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    cellH = c.bounds.size.height;

    // see if list will overlow maxH(eight)
    cellsH = cellH * mValues.count;
    if (cellsH > maxH) {
        h = maxH;
    } else {
        h = cellsH;
    }

    return CGRectMake(l, t, w, h);
}

#pragma mark - TableView Delegate functions

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return  1;  // this is a one section table
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return mValues.count;   // should be called for only one section
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // try to resuse a cell if possible
    static NSString *RESUSE_IDENTIFIER = @"myResuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:RESUSE_IDENTIFIER];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:RESUSE_IDENTIFIER];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [mValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (mValue == indexPath.row){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // save value and hide view
    mValue = indexPath.row;
    [self updateButtonTitle];
    [mBackgroundV setHidden:YES];
    [mTV setHidden:YES];
    [delegate itemSelected:mValue];
}
@end
```